# Amazon cli image doesn't work with Gitlab CI

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run the aws command (to invalidate cloudfront) using official aws image and have the following config of .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
static-invalidation:
  <<: *production-env
  stage: static_invalidation
  image: amazon/aws-cli:latest
  variables:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $CLOUDFRONT_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $CLOUDFRONT_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  script:
    - aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION --invalidation-batch file://deployment/configs/inv-batch.json
```

The job fails with the following error:

```py
Using docker image sha256:00cf4f100b03d1b26e93cce377c1311c34efa753e379cd5c6ea5d458337cbaab for amazon/aws-cli:2.2.17 with digest amazon/aws-cli@sha256:39e9898fc43f618636a2190f82b9babcdc618d054e66b49c9959b9cd23285ade ...
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:
  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
accessanalyzer                           | acm                                     
acm-pca                                  | alexaforbusiness
...
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 252
```

Any ideas why it's not working?
When I run the command locally it works.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`amazon/aws-cli` docker has set entrypoint to `aws` as it's expected to be executed as

```sh
$ docker run amazon/aws-cli cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ...
```

but gitlab expects entry point to shell so it can then execute `script` commands.

Check out gitlab documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#available-settings-for-image

You will find there how to override docker image entrypoint.

---

Working config is:

```yaml
image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli:2.2.18
    entrypoint: [""]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to set the `entrypoint` to `/bin/sh -c` to keep your container alive and run your script in one line...

```
  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli:2.11.18
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
  script:
    - |
      echo "Deploying API to EKS..."
      aws eks --region $AWS_EKS_REGION...
```